# How would I make it so a flask API can only be used with my ReactJS app?

Tags: authentication, flask

I am creating a new flask API and I am needing to learn how to only allow my application to send and receive info from my API.

I'm not sure how I would go about this. (As I am a fairly new developer)

The web application itself will be with React. The API with python flask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to limit requests on your API from a specific application, you need to use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). In Flask, there is a package named [`flask-cors`](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) using which you can limit requests from the origin (URL) of your web application.

**Installation**

```sh
$ pip install -U flask-cors
```

**Usage**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Allow requests only from your web app's domain or the development server.
# If you don't include `http://localhost:3000`, you might gets CORS Access Denied
# Error during development.
app.config["CORS_ORIGINS"] = ["https://your-web-app.com", "http://localhost:3000"]

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

You will need to grasp few concepts before consuming an API from any front end framework like React.

1. [Promises](https://youtu.be/_8gHHBlbziw)
2. [Fetch API](https://youtu.be/cuEtnrL9-H0)

That being done, you can consume the API from any React application as shown below.

**Using function components (hooks)**

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5v2tr?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  function getUsers() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => setUsers(users))
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  });

  return (
    <>
      {users ? (
        users.map((user) => <h1 key={user.name}>{user.name}</h1>)
      ) : (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Using class components**

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/t2f5y?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: null
  };

  getUsers() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => this.setState({ users }))
      .catch((err) => {
        throw new Error(err);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {users ? (
          users.map((user) => <h1 key={user.name}>{user.name}</h1>)
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading...</h1>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Footnotes**

The Codesandbox examples attached above make use of a mock API named [JSON Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com).

Comment: This solution only prevents different origins from accessing the API. That said, it doesn't consider direct access via the browser. Suppose the API is hosted on https://www.api.com. Then any user can go directly to https://www.api.com/get_all_user_data and fetch all the user data.